# htaccess mod_rewrite without .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with htaccess because I would like to have my URLs SEO friendly. And that's  all good but I can't go on the URL without using .php

My URL is:

```
http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem?id=3
```

And I want it to be:

```
http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem/3/
```

I've searched online and I've written code that made it work, the only problem is that I can't go to the URL unless I use .php
My htaccess code is this(I'm a noob if it comes to htaccess):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rasolutions\.eu\/" [R=301,L]

# No PERL access/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^blogitem/([0-9]+)/$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^blog/([0-9]+)/$    blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]

# Home redirect.
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Thank you very much for helping! Sorry for the bad English, it isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: You can remove the second and third `RewriteEngine On` as it is turned on already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rasolutions\.eu\/" [R=301,L]

# No PERL access/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^blogitem/([0-9]+)/$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^blog/([0-9]+)/$    blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]

# Home redirect.
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Multiviews should allow Apache to search out a nearest match, e.g. without the ".php" extension.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for that quick response. It almost works, the only problem is that blog/1/ works but blogitem/1/ doesn't. I don't know why. If I'm going to http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem/6/ it will send me to http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem/6/blog

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
# Home redirect.
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# No PERL access/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
RewriteRule ^ http://rasolutions.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]+)/?$ blogitem.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$  blog.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```